# Array not being updated inside if statement C

Tags: c, arrays, if-statement, modulus

In the following code, i'm trying to count the number of different odd numbers in an given int. For this, I first used modulus to separate the integer into single digit ints and then put all the odd numbers into the array oddInts. This works fine however, the array seems to hold the values only inside the if statement. Outside the if statement, the array seems to have a bunch of random numbers.

My question is, how can I modify an array inside the if statement so the array can be manipulated afterwards.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int lenHelper(unsigned x) {
    if(x>=1000000000) return 10;
    if(x>=100000000) return 9;
    if(x>=10000000) return 8;
    if(x>=1000000) return 7;
    if(x>=100000) return 6;
    if(x>=10000) return 5;
    if(x>=1000) return 4;
    if(x>=100) return 3;
    if(x>=10) return 2;
    return 1;
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    int inputInt=987654;
    int size=lenHelper(inputInt);
    int input[size];
    int count=0;
    // int oddCount=0;
    int oddInts[5];

    for (int i=0; i<size; i++) {
        input[i]=inputInt%10;
        inputInt=inputInt/10;

        if (input[i]%2==1) {
            //  oddCount=input[i];
            oddInts[i]=input[i];
            printf("%d", oddInts[i]);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `lenHelper(987654)` looks like it would return 6, so why is `oddInts` declared to only hold 5 values?

Comment: Did you mean: `oddInts[ i/2 ] = input[i];` ?

Comment: Please **use the debugger** (and enable all warnings and debug info in your compiler)

Answer (score 1):

If I have understood correctly then array oddInts must keep frequencies of how often each odd digit is present in the original number. If so then the code can look the following way

```
// preceding declarations

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    unsigned int inputInt = 987654;
    int size = lenHelper( inputInt );
    unsigned int input[size];
    unsigned int oddInts[5] = { 0 };

    for ( int i = 0; i < size; i++ ) 
    {
        input[i] = inputInt % 10;
        inputInt = inputInt / 10;

        if ( input[i] % 2 == 1 ) 
        {
            int j = ( input[i] - 1 ) / 2;
            oddInts[j]++;
            printf( "%d\t%d", input[i], oddInts[j] );
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

As for me then I would write the program the following way (using the C that is before C99)

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define BASE    10

int main( void ) 
{
    while ( 1 )
    {
        unsigned int oddInts[BASE / 2] = { 0 };
        unsigned int x = 0;
        unsigned int i;

        printf( "Enter a positive integer number (0 - exit): " );

        scanf( "%u", &x );

        if ( !x ) break;

        do 
        {
            unsigned int digit = x % BASE;

            if ( digit % 2 == 1 ) oddInts[(digit - 1 ) / 2]++;
        } while ( x /= BASE );

        for ( i = 0; i < BASE / 2; i++ )
        {
            printf( "\n%u\t%u", 2 * i + 1, oddInts[i] );
        }
        puts( "" );
    }

    return 0;
}
```

If the input is

```
1234576543
0
```

then output will be

```
Enter a positive integer number (0 - exit): 1234576543
1   1
3   2
5   2
7   1
9   0
Enter a positive integer number (0 - exit): 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Now you don't do anything when the digit is not odd, so these elements of array can contain rubbish, that's why you have random numbers there.
I added "else" to the code to help you to understand the cause of the problem.

```
 for (int i=0; i<size; i++) {
    input[i]=inputInt%10;
    inputInt=inputInt/10;

    if (input[i]%2==1) {
        //  oddCount=input[i];
        oddInts[i]=input[i];
        printf("%d ", oddInts[i]);
    } else {
        oddInts[i] = 0; //the digit is not odd
    }
}


for (i=0; i<size; i++) {
        printf("%d\n", oddInts[i]);
}
```

Also your code doesn't count different odd numbers as it is. It just fill in the array oddInts with all the odd digits it found in the number. 
It doesn't count them and doesn't check if the digits are different.

Answer (score 0):

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{

    int value=0;     //Newly added variable

    for (int i=0; i<size; i++) {
        input[i]=inputInt%10;
        inputInt=inputInt/10;

        if (input[i]%2==1) {
            //  oddCount=input[i];
            oddInts[value]=input[i];     //oddInts[] is updated  
            printf("%d", oddInts[value]);//oddInts[value] is printed
            value++;                     //'value' is incremented
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int lenHelper(unsigned x) {
        if(x>=1000000000) return 10;
        if(x>=100000000) return 9;
        if(x>=10000000) return 8;
        if(x>=1000000) return 7;
        if(x>=100000) return 6;
        if(x>=10000) return 5;
        if(x>=1000) return 4;
        if(x>=100) return 3;
        if(x>=10) return 2;
        return 1;
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
        int inputInt=987654;
        int size=lenHelper(inputInt);
        int input[size];
        int count=0,i,k=0;
        /* int oddCount=0; */
        int oddInts[5];

        for ( i=0; i<size; i++)
        {
                input[i]=inputInt%10;
                inputInt=inputInt/10;
                if (input[i]%2==1)
                {
                        //  oddCount=input[i];
                        oddInts[k]=input[i];
                        k++;
                }
        }

        for(i=0;i<k;i++)
        {
                printf("%d", oddInts[i]);
        }
        return 0;
}
```